# Inconsistent of auto-redirection after using javaexecute to set value

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

The website supposed to work this way --> 1. connect to server 2. click one button then a popup for logging in will appear 3. fill in account username and password 4. click log in button (the other button from the one in the second step) and the pop up is gone 5. auto-redirection to another page

However, of 5 trials of using the code the same url, only two times do the website auto-redirect(which is supposed to be) while the rest it works fine until step 4 with no errors shown and stay on the same page. Here are the exact code I used:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=path);
driver.get("url")

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"xpath"))
)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))
    )

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value ="gmail",username)


password = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))
    )
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value ='pass',password)


login = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm-    signin"]/div[3]/div/button'))
     )
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", login)
```

Does anybody knows what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Why not using the selenium click ? Is it possible to share the html or website ?

Comment: I mean I could use the click and send_keys but I just want to 1.make it faster, so I tried the executescript and 2. I just wonder why wouldn't it work the same

Comment: I don't think that executing javascript via python will give you better performance.